# Regarding initialization of bool array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was doing one programming problem, there I initialized the bool array like following:-

```
bool hash[n] = {0};
```

I submitted the code and I got the wrong answer. I tried to figure out what is the problem. Then I changed the above statement to following:-

```
bool hash[n];
fill(hash, hash + n, 0);
```

This gave correct answer. I didn't understand why the bool array initialization is not working.

After that just out of curiosity, I tried following:-

```
bool hash[n] = {0};
fill(hash, hash + n, 0);
```

I submitted the code and I got wrong answer. This really blew my mind. Any inputs?

Comment: is `n` compile time value or do you use VLA?

Comment: no it is given at runtime

Comment: @prat then `bool hash[n];` is not legal C++. In C++ array dimensions must be *compile time constants*.You are just unlucky enough to have a compiler which accepts illegal C++.

Comment: Of course would need to see a complete program to explain what is going on. None of your three options look wrong to me (apart from the array).

Comment: But obviously *not* lucky enough for it to initialise it properly :-)

Comment: @john, I think C++ now supports runtime declaration of arrays, I have been using for a while, didn't get any issue. I am trying to refer to " runtime declaration of dimensions of array"

Comment: @prat *I think C++ now supports runtime declaration of arrays* -- No, C++ does not support this.  You are another victim of the bogus syntax.  If you want a rude awakening, try your code with the Visual C++ compiler, latest and greatest version.  You will see the code will not compile.

Comment: @prat C++ hasn't included VLAs yet, with length/size declared at runtime. However some compilers do accept such syntax, following C99.

Comment: most compilers need to be passed flags to be fully standard conformant, read here on vlas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard the thing is: you don't need them, because you can use `std::vector`

Comment: @prat What your compiler accepts and what the C++ standard accepts are not the same thing. Every compiler is different of course, but this issue, *variable length arrays* (VLA), is a particularly notorious deviation from the C++ standard which is accepted by the g++ compiler (in it's default mode). Just think of it as a trap to catch the unwary beginner.

Comment: @idclev463035818: but `std::vector<bool>` is criticized a lot ^_^

Comment: @Jarod42 I stopped critizing at some point. Workarounds are simple `std::vector<MyBool>`, `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<some_enum>` are all not perfect but do the job. `std::vector<bool>` is not a vector of bools, but I also dont blame a stone for not being a flower :P But yeah, sorry I missed the `bool` here

Comment: [Visual C++ online compiler](https://rextester.com/IQIJ30200).  Doesn't compile.

Comment: @idclev463035818: No need to worry about "missing bool". For typical programming problems, `vector<bool>` works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error by going through a few online c++ compilers. (some of them accept VLAs following C99 and don't throw any errors)

Writing

```cpp
int n=20;
bool hash[n]={0};
```

throws:

> main.cpp:6:13: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized bool hash[n]={0};
>        ^
>   1 error generated.
>   compiler exit status 1

As extensively discussed in the comments above, declaring array size/length at runtime is not a feature of standard C++.

However, this would work:

```cpp
int n=20;
bool hash[n];
```

because the array elements are not specified/initialized.

For reproducability, [here](https://repl.it/languages/cpp11) is the link of the online compiler which produced this case.

Always use vectors for such cases.